# Implementing the producer-consumer pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Let's say that I have 200 expensive method calls to make (each with different arguments). For some reason, I can execute 5 of those calls in parallel, but no more. I *could* execute them one at a time, but doing 5 at a time is 5 times faster.

I want to always be executing five things. I don't want to queue five, wait until all five are done, and then queue five more. If I queue A,B,C,D,E and C finishes first, I want to immediately replace it with F, even if A and B aren't done yet.

I've been reading into this problem, since it's something I can imagine happening on a regular basis. The solution seems to be the producer-consumer pattern, and Ruby has some structures built into its standard library for use with that pattern (`Queue` and `SizedQueue`). I've played around with code samples, read some of the documentation, and I think I have a rough understanding of it. But I have some questions I'm not confident in my solution, and the whole area of multithreading is new ground for me, so I thought I'd ask here to make sure I'm not, you know, totally wrong and just lucky.

So here's a test program I wrote:

```
q = Queue.new
q << 'balloon'
q << 'sandwich'
q << 'clown'
q << 'fairy floss'
q << 'ferris wheel'
q << 'magician'
q << 'cake'
q << 'present'
q << 'chip'
q << 'game'
q << 'animal'

consumer_1 = Thread.new do
  until q.empty?
    sleep rand(0..10)
    print "#{q.pop}\n"
  end
end

# consumer 2 and 3 are identical to consumer 1

[consumer_1, consumer_2, consumer_3].map(&:join)
```

The queue holds a list of things we need for a birthday party. 3 consumer threads work through the list.

This works, my questions are:

If it's the number of consumers that determines how many items are being worked in parallel, what's the point of having a *sized* queue?

Would a sized queue only be useful in situations where the tasks are infinite, unknown, or vast in number and you want to pause before filling the queue up?

Have I failed to implement the problem properly? Creating multiple threads by hand and then calling `join` on them seems slightly messy. Is there a better solution?

Comment: [The `producer_consumer` gem's source](https://github.com/aphyr/producer_consumer) might prove educational.

Answer (score 2):

A SizedQueue prevents a producer from adding items faster then the consumers can consume.

**[SizedQueue#push](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/SizedQueue.html#method-i-push)**

> If there is no space left in the queue, waits until space becomes
>   available

**[Queue#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Queue.html#method-i-pop) / [SizedQueue#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/SizedQueue.html#method-i-pop)**

> If the queue is empty, the calling thread is suspended until data is
>   pushed onto the queue.

**SizedQueue vs Queue**

```
require 'thread'
require 'logger'

queue = SizedQueue.new(3)
#queue = Queue.new # goes berzerk
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

Thread.new do
  item = 0
  loop do
    item += 1
    queue << item
    logger.info "#{item} produced"
  end
end

consumers = 2.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      item = queue.pop
      logger.info "consumed #{item}"
      sleep item
    end
  end
end

consumers.each(&:join)
```

**How to stop the worker threads**

```
require 'thread'
require 'logger'

queue = Queue.new
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
consumers_count = 5

end_object = BasicObject.new

consumers = consumers_count.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    until (item = queue.pop) == end_object
      logger.info "consumed #{item}"
    end
  end
end

1000.times.each { |item| queue << item }
consumers_count.times { queue << end_object }

consumers.each(&:join)
```

**Further reading:**

- [a writeup about Queue and SizedQueue](http://iamserg.io/writings/2014/queue-and-sized-queue/)